# HowTo: Redis in production server

Tags: python, django, nginx, redis

I'm a newbie in setting up the cache system and the production server. I already setup my previous Django script in my production server(Django + Nginx + UWSGI + Supervisor + Ubuntu 12.04) with this community and my friend's help.

Now I'm newly powering my social stream with Redis. I don't know how to install it in the production server with Django and Nginx.

I really don't understand the code here http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRedis It shows that this code

```
server {
  location / {
    set $redis_key $uri;

    redis_pass     name:6379;
    default_type   text/html;
    error_page     404 = /fallback;
  }

  location = /fallback {
    proxy_pass backend;
 }
}
```

is just for simple Caching. What is simple caching in Redis?. I'm **using set, get, list and hash commands** from redis. Is that code enough for what I'm doing?

If not, could anyone give me the nginx setup for Django with Redis.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Start with this:
https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py

```
$ sudo pip install redis
```

Or this:
https://github.com/sebleier/django-redis-cache

Redis stores and retrieves data using the key-value model.

When you set a key you'll also set a TTL for the key.
http://redis.io/commands/ttl

```
redis> SET mykey "Hello"
OK
redis> EXPIRE mykey 10
(integer) 1
redis> TTL mykey
(integer) 10
redis>
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I already saw those things, So I don't need to use Nginx for setting up Redis in production server? which means the setup is same as we are doing in the Development server, right?